# Codeigniter 4 and fullcalendar

Tags: php, fullcalendar, codeigniter-4

Im trying to get database data events to load in to me fullcalendar but im not really succeeding. Been trying for many hours now but i dont know why it cant find it. I've been var_dump the data and it is working from the database. I basically have problem to get it into the calendar.

Controller function:

```
    public function getEvents($start, $end)
{
    $calendar_model = new \App\Models\CalendarModel();

    $event_data = $calendar_model->get_events();

    foreach ($event_data as $row) {
        $data = [
            'ID'          => $row->ID,
            'description' => $row->description,
            'title'       => $row->$title,
            'start'       => $row->start,
            'end'         => $row->end,
        ];
    }

    return json_encode($data);


}
```

calendar function:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {


eventSources: [
     {
        timeZone: 'UTC',

         events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
            var start = moment('2021-01-10T00:00:00').unix();
            var end = moment('2021-01-15T00:00:00').unix();
             $.ajax({
             url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>/CalenderController/getEvents',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: {
             // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
             start: start,
             end: end
             },
             success: function(msg) {
                 var events = msg.events;
                 callback(events);
             }
             });
         }
     },
 ],

      initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
    });
    // console.log(eventSources);
    calendar.render();
  })
```

Ive been trying many types of date types to see if any is working but I cant get it to work..

and here is a picture of my response in log:
[img of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raKkU.png)

It is supposed to show event start date from 2021-01-10 to 2021-01-15

Comment: You're using an old version of the events function. I guess you found an example online but didn't realise it's out of date. Please always check the documentation - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Comment: Anyway a 404 error means you got the URL wrong, pointing to your PHP controller function

Comment: Verify if you are extending Controller in the class that have the controller function. Try to rename the function  and the controller name in small case in the route using this ```calendercontroller/events```

Comment: I don't know where the problem is but I do believe(might be wrong) return function does not work while using AJAX calls try using echo instead in PHP. Also as @ADyson pointed out I do think the url pointer given for Javascript AJAX is given wrong path due to 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return method in Codeigniter 4

```
return json_encode($data);
```

From to.

```
return $this->response->setJSON($data, true);
```